# How can I chain vim commands when one expects a user input

Tags: vim

As a minimal example, say I'd like to search in the current buffer then save it.

something like `/` [user input...] 
then `w`

how would you chain that in a single command ?

It's pointless in my example, but the real situtation is :
`:GoRename [user input] <CR>`
then `:GoBuildTags '' <CR>`

And something like that doesn't work :
`nnoremap <leader>rr :GoRename <bar> :GoBuildTags ''<CR>`

Comment: Are you trying to make a mapping or command?

Comment: yes, I update the question

Comment: I'd use Ctrl+v followed by Ctrl+M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The real situtation is: `:GoRename [user input] <CR>` then `:GoBuildTags '' <CR>`

My recommendation here is that you create a new user-command such as `:GoRenameBuildTags` that executes the two commands, passing its argument to the first command.

You can usually chain commands together using `|`, but that would require that the `:GoRename` command was declared with `-bar`, which is not really the case... So you'll need to wrap it in a `:execute` so that you can separate it from the second command.

So you can define the command as follows:

```
command! -nargs=? -complete=customlist,go#rename#Complete
    \ GoRenameBuildTags
    \ execute "GoRename" <q-args>
    \ | GoBuildTags ''
```

I'm using here the same `-nargs` and `-complete` as the original `GoRename` definition, since you're forwarding the passed argument to that command, it makes sense to match it.